# How does UIBarButtonItem know which UIBarStyle the UIToolBar uses?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitoolbar

In Xcode ui builder when one set the UIBarStyle of the UIToolBar (such as BlackTranslucent, for example), the UIToolBarItem matches the background images to it. How does the UIToolBarItem know which style it should use?

I'm trying to do a put a custom colored image on top of the regular background tile (programatically merge a given image on top of the background image). I want to the code to be generalizable enough so that it is able to handle all UIBarStyles. That means I want to know when UIToolBarItem decides which background to use and intercept it so I can compose the button image on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to see apple's implementation of UIBarbuttonItem, I posit that they do *not*, in fact, know what the style of their UIToolbar is.  If you look closely, they have the same alpha as their toolbar, and the same overlay (indicative of a subview).  Therefore, any image that is below this highlighted layer, added as a subview, should conform to the UIToolbar's style.  If you want to use multiple images though (one for each barStyle), you can determine it with `self.myToolbar.barStyle` and plan appropriately at -viewDidLoad time.  As for true image drawing, subclass UIToolbar and override `-drawRect:` and use `[UIImage drawInRect:rect];`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to as the overlay. You mean the glassy look? I'm not sure when you added as a subview, how it would comform to UIBarStyle automatically? From I can tell there are two images, when unpressed and when pressed.

Comment: Subviews automatically adopt the basic appearance aspects of their superview (alpha, any z-ordered layers above them).  The whole two images thing means you want a UIButton.